# Deleting certain rows without a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe with car repair data. It also tells me if a car broke down (and got repaired). I would like to get rid of all rows with repair events after the car broke down.

```
Car <- c('A','A','B')
Damage <-c("Wheels","Motor","Motor")
date <-c('01-01-2015','01-01-2016','01-01-2016')
Broke_down <-c(1,0,1)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Car,date,Damage,Broke_down))
```

Basically, I want to remove all lines that occur for a car after the dummy was 1.

So in this case the output would have to be:

```
"Car"        "date"          "Damage"     "Broke_down"
 A           01-01-2015       Wheels         1
 B           01-01-2016       Motor          1
```

Best,
Felix

Comment: Your example is poorly chosen since it happens to be easily solved with a much simpler approach though that would not be correct for other cases. A better choice of example data would prevent too simple solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `split` and `lapply`, data preparation is the same as in the question:

```
df2 <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(df, df$Car),
    function(x){
      x[1:which.min(x$Broke_down==1), ]
    })
)
```

Explanation:
`split` gives a list of `data.frames`
`lapply` applies the function in it's second argument and returns a list of the results
finally `do.call` calls `rbind` with the resulting list of `data.frames` giving you one long `data.frame` again.

There are similar but faster solutions using `data.table` and `dplyr`.

Comment: Maybe `which.min` instead of `min(which(...))`? (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the update in OP's post

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[cummin(Broke_down) > 0], Car]
#    Car       date Damage Broke_down
#1:   A 01-01-2015 Wheels          1
#2:   B 01-01-2016  Motor          1
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(Broke_down, Car, FUN = cummin) > 0),]
#  Car       date Damage Broke_down
#1   A 01-01-2015 Wheels          1
#3   B 01-01-2016  Motor          1
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but `lapply` and `do.call` do the trick:

```
df_out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$Car),function(x){

  df_sub <- df[df$Car==x,]
  df_sub[1:which(df_sub$Broke_down == 1)[1],]

}))

> df_out
  Car       date Damage Broke_down
1   A 01-01-2015 Wheels          1
3   B 01-01-2016  Motor          1
```